# Quick warmup before descent

Tags: mountain-bike, fitness

When going for a day ride, climb a hill, have a beer and a sandwich and then shread on the familiar path down - all is well and fun.

However, if I go on a after-work-and-sleep-in-sleeping-bag ride or a multi-day ride, it is common to begin the day with a rough descent. I have been sleeping on hard ground, my joints have been immobilized for 8 hours and on top of that it's the coldest part of the day.

In such a situation, **what would be a good sub-five minutes workout to prepare my body for extended descent?** I am also recovering from right shoulder and right knee trauma.

Comment: Ride down a couple of meters of the descent, ride up again, repeat until satisfied?

Comment: @stijn, sorry, can't make turns that sharp. I will try it with 3 meters next time and report back is this nicer, compared to traditional martial arts warmup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 40, and have back and joint issues that make getting up in the morning hard work.  If I get-up-and-go its terrible for the first half-hour.  So here's what helps me:

- Full flexion of joints.  That means pushing your limbs to the ir comfortable maximum extensions then holding for a few seconds, then a little further.  Nothing rough.
- A hot shower - where possible.
- Warmth - standing in a sunny spot helps a heap, as does pressing a hot coffee cup against sore muscles.
- Food - eat your damn breakfast!
- Water - hydrate!
- Warmup ride - Do a short loop or gentle out and back to get limbered up.  Not going hard, just getting fluid into your joints and heating the muscles.
- Clothing - consider wearing a tighter compression top and pants.  These will get your muscles up to working temperature sooner.
- Sleeping clothes - don't wear the riding clothes while sleeping - you want to relax not be constrained.
- Gloves - I wear some home-made cotton gloves that cover 2/3 of the forearm. Again these help with keeping warmth in.

Getting sufficient sleep helps immensely.  Whatever helps you get to sleep is good too.  A plain sleeping bag is better on a sleeping mat, and picking somewhere without rocks/sticks is best.  I've never tried a camping hammock but some people swear by them.

Comment: Joint issues? You are high too often? Hehehe.

Comment: @vorac no, never.  Its an age thing - you'll find out :-P

Answer (score 0):

- stretching
- ride for 5-10 minutes on flat ground using a low gear

Comment: Totally right, but could you expand this to a bigger answer?  Adding specific stretches.

Comment: How would riding flat ground warm up the upper body?

Comment: Hmm. Stretching cold muscles is a great way to get injuries :-(